# how to script tmux to execute a script in a tmux session(window)

Tags: shell, script, tmux

I have this script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session top \; split-window -v \; split-window -h \; select-pane -t 0 \; split-window -h \; attach-session
```

I would like to execute a shell script in each directory. How would one accomplish this (`tmux new-session sh /path/script.sh \;`)?

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726532/108618).